# How to get only the mm/dd/year from strptime

Tags: python

I am getting time using the following code, if I print this value I am getting month, date, year and also the H, M, S. I just need `MM/DD,YEAR`, how do I get it?

```
  lastTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeStr, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  print lastTime
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print the datetime in the format `MM/DD,YEAR`:

```
print(lastTime.strftime('%m/%d,%Y'))
```

If you want the date in the format `MM-DD-YEAR`, use:

```
print(lastTime.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
```

---

Also note `lastTime` is a datetime.datetime object. The month, day and year are accessible through attributes:

```
lastTime.month, lastTime.day, lastTime.year
```

Comment: I am trying to print using Time=lastTime.month + '-' + lastTime.day + '-' + lastTime.year and running into error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: `lastTime.month` is an `int`, and `-` is a `str`. That is why you are getting the TypeError. Use `strftime` as shown in the post instead.

Answer (score 1):

As well as what @unutbu has mentioned - you can also make use of `str.format` which combines the ability to mix'n'match `strftime` and attribute access of the datetime object.

Random example:

```
>>> '{0:%m%d%Y}-{0.month}'.format(dt)
'11262012-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

A datetime with the time set to zero will represent just a date.

```
lastTime = lastTime.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```